# Where Singleton object is allocated?

Tags: swift, memory, singleton, allocation

I wanted to know where `myClass` objects allocated exactly so I drew allocation flow

```swift
class MyClass {
    static let shared = MyClass()
    private init() { }
}

let myClass = MyClass.shared
```

1. `myClass` constant is allocated in Stack
2. `myClass` constant point to Heap where `MyClass` is allocated
3. `MyClass.shared` static property point to `MyClass()` where allocated in Heap

Is this flow right? Am I misunderstood something?

[image: data diagram]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Swift allocates storage for `MyClass.shared` in the data segment, initialized to nil. The data segment's layout and initial contents are defined by the executable file. Historically, the heap started immediately at the end of the data segment, but on modern 64-bit systems with address space layout randomization (ASLR), I don't know if that's still true.
- Swift also allocates a `swift_once_t` in the data segment to record whether `MyClass.shared` has been initialized yet.
- Swift generates a getter function for `MyClass.shared` in the code segment. The getter function uses the `swift_once_t` to initialize the storage of `MyClass.shared` the first time the getter is called. It looks approximately like this:

  ```
  var _storage_MyClass_shared: MyClass? = nil
  var _once_MyClass_shared: swift_once_t = .init() // essentially, false

  func _getter_MyClass_shared() -> MyClass {
      swift_once(&_once_MyClass_shared, {
          _storage_MyClass_shared = MyClass()
      })
      return _storage_MyClass_shared!
  }
  ```
- The instance of `MyClass` is stored on the heap. It starts with a word containing the `isa` pointer (to the `MyClass` metadata), followed by a word containing (usually) reference counts, followed by storage for the object's instance variables. In your case, there are no instance variables, so there is no additional storage. The blue box labeled `Myclass()` in your diagram, and the arrow pointing to it, do not exist.
- If `myClass` is at top-level (not inside a method or data type declaration), then it is also stored in the data segment along with another `swift_once_t` that tracks whether it's been initialized, and Swift generates a getter for it in the code segment.
- If `myClass` is an instance variable of a data type, then it is stored as part of its containing object, which may be either on the stack or the heap (in the case of a `struct`, `enum`, or tuple) or always on the heap (in the case of a `class` or `actor`).
- If `myClass` is a local variable in a function, then it is stored on the stack.